# map of structs using unique ptr : does not build on visual but works on clang

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, clang, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I'm having these two simple codes :

```
void f(){
    std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<int>> map_;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    map_[42] = std::move(p);
}
```

**does build**

```
struct test_s{
    int toto;
    std::unique_ptr<int> tata;
};
void f(){
    std::map<int,test_s> map_;
    test_s p;
    map_[42] = std::move(p);
}
```

**does not build because copy is forbidden on visual ctp120**
It does build on MAC with Clang 4.2

Anyone has an idea about what I should change to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly defining move constructor and move assignment operator is a workaround (tested with VS2010):

```
struct test_s{
    int toto;
    std::unique_ptr<int> tata;
    test_s() : toto(0) {}
    test_s& operator=(test_s&& o)
    {
        toto = o.toto;
        tata = std::move(o.tata);
        return *this;
    }
    test_s(test_s&& o) : toto(o.toto), tata(std::move(o.tata)) {}
};
```

As a guess, MSVC is not auto generating the move operations.